# Windows 10 device portal provisioning self signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, windows-10-desktop, self-signed-certificate

for Windows 10 **DESKTOP** device portal, has anyone been able to successfully  provision self-signed SSL certificate to device portal as per instruction found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-ssl?

I only need to connect from localhost, so using the same powershell scripts from the article, I created and installed a self-signed Root CA to `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` store, then used it to sign SSL certificate for `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1`. Each are exported as .pfx and provisioned to to device portal as instructed. `webmanagement` and the machine were restarted.

Yet, still couldn't get the 'Site not secure' page to go away on web browser. 
 Edge error code:

`DLG-FLAGS-SEC-CERT_CN_INVALILD`

Any insight is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, using `127.0.0.1` actually works, while `localhost` and `::1` doesn't. Also, since I'm using it in UWP C# implementation, I was suppose to add 'auto-' in front the login name in order to bypass CSRF protection. Once I did that, I can get 200 status code.